# How to delete a user's facebook data from firebase with firebase admin?

Tags: python, facebook, firebaseui, firebase-admin

I'm using firebase UI to authenticate users in a given frontend. Facebook authentication is enabled. I need to implement a [facebook data deletion callback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/data-deletion-callback) so I need to make my backend do two things:

1. delete/disable the facebook sign in method from the user that issued the data deletion request from facebook
2. delete every trace of facebook data from my firebase user (the *provider user info*) but **without deleting the user**

However, I can't find anything in [firebase admin's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) to delete facebook data. So, how can I delete the data?

PD: Keep in mind that I want to delete the user's *provider user info, but not the whole user* (because I need the user to stay there for data consistency)

Comment: In Node.js you can probably use [this API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UpdateRequest#optional-providerstounlink) to unlink a given auth provider from a user account. But it's not available in Python yet.

Comment: There is currently a [PR](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/pull/383) to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for a NodeJS implementation, this is how you can do it:

```js
module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const signedRequest = req.body.signed_request;
    const userObj = parseSignedRequest(signedRequest, FB_SECRET_KEY);
    const userRecord = await admin
      .auth()
      .getUserByProviderUid("facebook.com", userObj.user_id);
    await admin.auth().deleteUser(userRecord.uid);
    res.json({
      url: "<status_url>",
      confirmation_code: "<code>",
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // console.log(e);
    res.status(400).json({
      message: "Bad Request",
    });
  }
});

function base64decode(data: string) {
  while (data.length % 4 !== 0) {
    data += "=";
  }
  data = data.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");
  return Buffer.from(data, "base64").toString("utf-8");
}

function parseSignedRequest(signedRequest: string, secret: string) {
  var encoded_data = signedRequest.split(".", 2);
  // decode the data
  var sig = encoded_data[0];
  var json = base64decode(encoded_data[1]);
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  if (!data.algorithm || data.algorithm.toUpperCase() != "HMAC-SHA256") {
    throw Error(
      "Unknown algorithm: " + data.algorithm + ". Expected HMAC-SHA256"
    );
  }
  var expected_sig = crypto
    .createHmac("sha256", secret)
    .update(encoded_data[1])
    .digest("base64")
    .replace(/\+/g, "-")
    .replace(/\//g, "_")
    .replace("=", "");
  if (sig !== expected_sig) {
    throw Error("Invalid signature: " + sig + ". Expected " + expected_sig);
  }
  return data;
}
```

PS. There is no way to just unlink providers via Firebase Admin SDK for now so best we can do is delete the user data.

Comment: How exactly do I create a url?

Comment: @Andrew you can just create a express api endpoint which returns the current status of user data.

Comment: @dskaet How exactly does this status have to look like? Is a web page with a text like "your account is deleted", enough?  I mean my deletion takes like 5 seconds

Comment: yes its only for the user to confirm whether the data was deleted or not...so yes only a text would suffice.